# How to access dynamically added field value in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap, react-dom

I've a Component, In which I've one dropdown, which will populate with DB. Now I'm injecting this component whenever **Add Field** button clicks in other Component (May be more than one time). So how to fetch the data from this dynamic dropdown and attach to FormData, and send it to backend. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Below I'm just giving Idea of my component through Code.

Comment: please share code that you have tried

Comment: @VahidAkhtar Let say I've two files, CreateUser.js (Main File) & InputElem.js (Dynamic Field File, which I'll inject everytime into the CreateUser file, on button Click) So below are the code for these two files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting code of that two files here, So it will be much easier to get know.

**CreateUser.js**

```
<Form.Label>Social Account Links</Form.Label>
<Form.Row>
  <Form.Group as={Col} className="col-md-3" controlId="formGridChannel">
    <Form.Control as="select" name="channel" value={channel} onChange={this.onChange}>
      {channels}  /** This channels will populate from DB through componentDidMount hook call */
    </Form.Control>
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group as={Col} className="col-md-8" controlId="formGridSocialUrl">
    <Form.Control type="url" name="socialUrl" value={socialUrl} placeholder="Social Profile Link" onChange={this.onChange} />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group as={Col} className="col-md-1" controlId="formGridSocialLink">
    <Button variant="danger" type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({ fieldCount: fieldCount + 1 })}>Add Field</Button>
  </Form.Group>
</Form.Row>

{Array(fieldCount).fill(<InputElem channels={channels} />)}
```

**InputElem.js**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { channels: '', channel: '', socialUrl: '' };
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

/** Hook Call to receive channels as Props from Parent Component (CreateUser.js) */
componentDidMount = () => this.setState({ channels: this.props.channels });

onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

/** Render Part */
<Form.Row>
  <Form.Group as={Col} className="col-md-3" controlId="formGridChannel">
    <Form.Control as="select" name="channel" value={channel} onChange={this.onChange}>
      {channels}
    </Form.Control>
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group as={Col} className="col-md-8" controlId="formGridSocialUrl">
    <Form.Control type="url" name="socialUrl" value={socialUrl} placeholder="Brand Social Link" onChange={this.onChange} />
  </Form.Group>
</Form.Row>
```

Advance Thanks, for helping me out.